# If $G$ is a group with $|G|\ge2$ and has no subgroups except the two trivial ones, then $G$ is cyclic and of prime order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

So I'm working with algebra and have to deal with this problem. I can't see the logic to start the problem. I know the definition of a group and cyclic group. Any suggestion would be so great! I'm using the book from Hungerford.

**Problem:** Prove that if $G$ is a group with $|G|\geq2$ and no subgroups except for the two trivial ones (i.e. $\{e_G\}$ and $G$) then $G$ is cyclic and of prime order.

Comment: If $G$ is a group with $|G|\ge2$, then $G$ has an element besides the identity; consider the group generated by that element

Answer (score 5):

If $|G| \geq 2$, then $G$ has some prime factor $p$. By [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_theorem_(group_theory)), $G$ has an element $g$ with order $p$.

Consider the subgroup generated by $g$. This subgroup is a cyclic group of $p$ elements. But since the only nontrivial subgroup is $G$ itself, we conclude that this subgroup is indeed $G$, and so $G$ is cyclic with prime order.

Comment: Okay, I look the theorem up and it appear in section 9.3 in the textbook. Is there another approach, i.e. we assume we do not know the theorem?

Comment: @JoeyAdams Choose any element $g \in G$, and the subgroup generated by $g$. This is a cyclic group, and hence the whole group is cyclic. Also, $C_{ab}$ has $C_a$ as a subgroup, so the order must be prime.

Answer (score 3):

As $G\ne\{e_G\}$, you can pick $a\in G\setminus\{e_G\}$. Then the subgroup $\langle a\rangle$ generated by $a$ is $\ne\{e_G\}$, hence $G=\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic. The order of $a$ must be either $1$, or a prime, or composite, or infinite.

- As $a\ne e_G$, the order cannot be $1$.
- If it is infinite, it makes $G=\langle a\rangle\cong \Bbb Z$, but that has additional subgroups, e.g. $2\Bbb Z$.
- If it is composite, say $nm$ with $n,m\ge 2$, we similarly have $G\cong \Bbb Z/nm\Bbb Z$, which has $n\Bbb Z/nm\Bbb Z$ as additional subgroup.

Remains only the option that the order is prime.

Answer (score 2):

One doesn't need to assume $G$ is finite: every infinite group has proper nontrivial subgroups. Indeed, take $g\in G$, $g\ne1$. If $\langle g\rangle$ is proper, we're done; otherwise $\langle g\rangle=G$; in this case we have
$$
\{1\}\subsetneq\langle g^2\rangle\subsetneq\langle g\rangle=G
$$
Suppose now $G$ is finite. Take $g\in G$, $g\ne 1$. If $\langle g\rangle\ne G$, we're done. Otherwise $\langle g\rangle=G$. If the order $n$ of $g$ is composite, say $n=ab$, with $1<a<n$, then the order of $g^a$ is less than $n$ and greater than $1$. Therefore $\{1\}\subsetneq\langle g^a\rangle\subsetneq\langle g\rangle=G$.

Thus the assumption can only hold for $|G|$ a prime and in this case it indeed holds, because subgroups can only have order $1$ or $|G|$.